# Mechanical Turk / Cmd line tools / Qualification / #set and #foreach in xml

Tags: mechanicalturk

In the Amazon Mechanical Turk command line tools (I am using version: aws-mturk-clt-1.3.0), in one of the samples (site_filter_qual: "Website Filtering Qualification", file site_filter_qual.question), there is code that looks something like this:

```
#set( $urls = [ "http://news.bbc.co.uk/", http://..., ...])

#foreach ( $url in $urls )
...
```

I am wondering :

- a) What is the language used here (it's
  not Perl and not PHP, right?);
- b)
  Where (on Amazon site or elsewhere) I
  could read about these constructs;
- c)
  How to implement tuples (pairs), e.g.

// in Python:

```
>> data = [("http://news.bbc.com", "NEWS"), ("http://google.com", "SEARCH"), ...]
>> for (url, category) in data:
>>     ....
```

-- or something similar?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It's a Velocity template (part of the Apache project). The good news is that it's a reasonably flexible language that you can manipulate. The better news is that you can (since I believe all the CLT and SDK code is open) actually create new constructs to override or expand on anything that's not part of Velocity out-of-the-box.

To answer your questions directly:

a) Velocity

b) http://velocity.apache.org/

c) You can use two separate arrays. Not pretty, I realize, but it'll work.

Comment: - 1) THANKS!!!
 - 2) "use two arrays": I still dont get it, could you please give a short example? 

I mean, -- I probably need smth. like

    #set( $urls = [...])
    #set( $cats = [...])

-- but foreach still won't work? I need smth. like 

> for (int i = 0; i < len($urls); i++)
>     do_smth_with $urls[i] .... 

-- but are these constructs there? what is the syntax?

I didn't find any loops except "foreach" at http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html (:_.

// Although this very page *mentions* "Hashtable" -- w/o bothering to describe the syntax! Sick!!!

Comment: PS: sorry but apparently no formatting works in copmments to comments:-).

Comment: The suggestion to "use two arrays" was as a way to simulate tuples. Basically one array of keys (call it 'k' let's say) and another of values (call it 'v', say). You'd then get a tuple by calling k[1] and v[1]. Again, not a best-practice but if, for some reason, tuples aren't available it's a workaround to your Question #3.