# Apache Velocity: hashtable?

Tags: velocity

The [Velocity user guide](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#loops) mentions a "Hashtable". However there's no mentioning how to create one in this language.

So if you could show how to do this
-- so that I could write smth. like

```
#foreach( $key in $foo.keySet() )
    <li>Key: $key -> Value: $foo.get($key)</li>
#end
```

-- I'd greatly appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance!

// PS: my original problem is : [Mechanical Turk / Cmd line tools / Qualification / #set and #foreach in xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348029/mechanical-turk-cmd-line-tools-qualification-set-and-foreach-in-xml) 
So please understand that I am not interested in learning Velocity -- I only need one quick hack if possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

In Velocity you would use the `#set` directive to create a map. To relate it to your example you might do something like:

```
#set($foo = {
    "NEWS": "http://news.bbc.com",
    "SEARCH": "http://google.com"
})
```

Then your foreach example above will do exactly what you need.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance - there should be a checkbox to the left of the answer to 'accept' it

Comment: Can anyone answer this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31116553/how-to-append-hash-tables-in-velocity-template